# how to read date in a specific format in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an excel column which is a date column with values like `1-JAN-22`.

But when I read using openpyxl the value shows as `2022-01-01 00:00:00`.

I'm extracting the value with `value = sh[cell_name].value`

How do I extract as I see in excel, `1-Jan-22`? I just want to extract this string.

Comment: Why? You just need the datetime data, then you can format it however you want... This is probably just the default way Excel shows the date... For example `strftime("%d-%b-%y")`

Comment: @Tomerikoo What if we need to extract format from date itself?

Comment: @DhairyaTripathi I don't quite understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows, try

```
value = datetime.date.strftime(sh['A1'].value, "%#d-%b-%y")
```

If on Linux, try

```
value = datetime.date.strftime(sh['A1'].value, "%-d-%b-%y")
```

Output:

```
'1-Jan-22'
```